# How to add an user to subscription list for an evault storage

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

What API should I use for subscription of Evault Storage Usage Notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following rest request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Notification_User_Subscriber/createObject

Method: post

{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "active":1,
         "notificationId":3,
         "userRecordId":498265,
         "preferences":[  
            {  
               "notificationPreferenceId":2,
               "value":"70"
            },
            {  
               "notificationPreferenceId":3,
               "value":"1"
            }
         ],
         "resourceRecord":{  
            "resourceTableId":4862895
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Replace: $user, $apiKey with you own information.
Also, replace these values:
**498265** with the user's identifier
**4862895** with the evault's identifier

**References:**

- [SoftLayer_Notification_User_Subscriber::createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Notification_User_Subscriber/createObject)

Comment: This api doesn't return boolean :-(

Comment: Yep, the method should and is returning a [SoftLayer_Notification_User_Subscriber](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Notification_User_Subscriber) object, there is a documentation issue about it.

Comment: My apologies, for this mistake, I hope this documentation issue could be fixed as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks ! :-) So this api will continuously return Subscriber object, not boolean and currently only documentation is issue, right?

Comment: Yes, it is only a documentation issue. The documentation should say that the method will return a [SoftLayer_Notification_User_Subscriber](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Notification_User_Subscriber) object